# List interpolation in command execution

Tags: bash

I have this code which accepts a list of arguments "a=b c=d e=f"

```
vars="--extra-vars \"$@\""
echo $vars
ansible-playbook play.yml -c local $vars
```

the purpose is that var will contain

```
--extra vars "a=b c=d e=f"
```

and then call the `ls` command like this

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -c local --extra-vars "a=b c=d e=f"
```

What *actually* happens when the command is being executed is this:

```
--extra-vars '"a=b' c=d 'e=f"'
```

How do I fix the interpolation?

Comment: did you try quoting, `"$vars"` ?

Comment: yes.
it outputs '--extra-vars "a=b c=d e=f"'
which is also bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell performs word splitting after parameter expansion.  Quotes resulting from parameter expansion represent themselves, and therefore do not prevent splitting.

If you absolutely must approach the problem this way, then you could consider using `eval` to re-parse the expanded command from scratch:

```
vars="--extra-vars '$@'"
echo $vars
eval "ansible-playbook play.yml -c local $vars"
```

Note that I have changed to single quotes around the extra argument values for greater (but still incomplete) protection against malicious inputs; it turns out to be a bit clearer, too.

If you can do so, however, then it is best to avoid `eval`.  If you're open to a bit more restructuring, then you might try something like this:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -c local --extra-vars "$*"
```

The main difference between `$@` and `$*` is how they interact with word splitting: when expanded within double quotes, the former expands to each positional parameter as a separate word (and not subject to further splitting) whereas the latter expands to a single word containing all the positional parameters, separated by the first character of `$IFS` (normally a space).